# I need to add 2nd CPU to my server running ESXi5.1, will it need to upgrade the licence too?

Tags: vmware-esxi, licensing, xeon

I have a server running with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz cpu, the main board have more PCI slots which I needed to use but it only works with a second CPU. here is the 2 important questions
- should the new CPU be like the running one exactly? 
- will I need to upgrade the Esxi licence too? now it is only for 1 physical CPU with any number of virtual CPUs.

thanks

Comment: Actually I don't think this one IS a duplicate - but your answers are; yes you need the CPU to be exactly the same and you need an ESXi licence for every physical CPU/socket used - not cores on those CPUs - so you will need another license yes, it just won't use the second CPU without it.

Comment: @Chopper3 The main reason I consider it a duplicate is because this is a question often asked of VMWare support. And the main response in the canonical answer is: ask your supplier.

Comment: @Reaces I understand but it was the 'do I need the exact same CPU' bit that I just wanted to answer.

Comment: @Reaces I already searched the previous questions, I supposed there was no duplication, also I was asking about two related points and wanted to get sure that the whole thing is understood by the colleges who may share their opinion. any way thanks for support